# Maven release to perform assembly single in a sub module

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I would like to run Maven release so that it should perform an `assembly:single` for a sub module.  I've included the `assembly:single` as part of the `install` of the sub module i.e. when you run `install` on the top level it builds the jar-with-dependencies.  But when the `release:perform` is run, even though it is configured to call `install` (as a a goal) it does not build the jar-with-dependencies.

How do I run a release at the top level and have this release perform an `assembly:single` on a sub-level using the release version?

```
<modules>
    <module>parent</module>
    <module>api</module>
    <module>testing</module>
    <module>main</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <goals>install</goals>
                <completionGoals>install</completionGoals>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is the sub module in `main`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Show your full pom files otherwise it's hard to guess what you are doing?

Comment: It is rather strange to set 'install' as the release goal (deploy looks better), but seeing the pom snippets, it should work. Maybe take a look if profiles can be an issue here. And also post your release command lines.

Comment: I use install because I don't want the project to be deployed anywhere.  Just want the versions incremented and checked into Git.  As far the command line goes I just use the plain release:prepare release:perform.

Comment: you use profiles in the poms?

Comment: change goals in maven-release-plugin by deploy instead of install and remove phase in execution section in maven-assembly-plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below configuration for release plugin:

```
<configuration>
  <preparationGoals>install</preparationGoals>
</configuration>
```

and start release preparation from scratch:

```
mvn release:prepare -Dresume=false
```

More detailed explanation of maven-release-plugin parameters:

`<goals>install</goals>` Called by release:perform. Release:perform clones your repo to target/checkout directory and calls install in it.

`<preparationGoals>install</preparationGoals>` Called by release:prepare. Install is executed before committing, default is clean verify.

`<completionGoals>install</completionGoals>` Called by release:prepare. Install is executed after committing. In this case whole build cycle is reiterated.

Comment: This is the configuration the OP is already using, but it doesn't do what he wants.

Comment: OP should use preparationGoals and -Dresume=false

Comment: Thanks so much this worked. Ultimately my mistake was using completionGoal rather than preparationGoal.

Comment: I've written this up in my blog see http://www.rationaljava.com/2015/02/maven-tip-all-about-executable-jars.html

Comment: Does the `preparationGoals` go in the parent or submodule build?